# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, localhost

Hi guys I am a bit new to flutter and I am making aa registration form but I am getting the error SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 when I submit the data, does anyone know how I could do this? I am not familiar with localhost etc. so an explanation would be appreciated if I need to change anything there.

```
  postData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse("http://localhost/xxx/api/xxxxxxxx.php"),
          body: {
            "name": _name.text,
            "email": _email.text,
            "phone": _phone.text,
            "pass": _pass1.text
          });
      print(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: use the ip of the machine instead of localhost

Comment: Are you trying this from simulator or physical device?